# CKEditor - Inserts Blank Content into the Database on First Click on the Save Button

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, ckeditor

Since this morning am trying to make this work, but failed. The CKEditor appears perfectly into the textarea, but when I try to save the content on the first mouse click on the save button, it doesn't inserts the content into the database. When I trigger my second click on save button again on the same content then its does insert into the database.

Textarea

```
<textarea class="txtPageContent" name="pageContent" id="pageContent"></textarea>
```

JavaScript Included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'pageContent' );
</script>
```

Plead do let me know for more informations.

Comment: Is this a AJAX-based saving what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, It's ajax based. 

I want to insert the content into MySQL. I have to click on the Submit button twice just to save the content into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Call `CKEDITOR.instances.pageContent.updateElement()` first ([see docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement)).

This will synchronize your `textarea` and your editor in terms of the content. Then, your AJAX request should serialize correct data. Just make sure that `updateElement()` call is before you gather data.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this. it works.

```
function returnToSubmit() {
    $('#ckeditor').val(CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor'].getData();
}
```

Also take a look into [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730723/2654789)